# Angular 8: Why do I receive null when using URL Query Strings?

Tags: java, angular

I am trying to consume the following web-service

```
@POST
@Path("/delete")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean deletePost(@QueryParam("idPost") String idPost) {
// logic here
}
```

However, trying to assign a value to the QueryParam idPost from angular does not work. Always idPost arrives with a value of null.

Try the 2 forms specified in the documentation but it does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
public deletePost(idPost: number): Observable<any> {
    const options = idPost ?
    { params: new HttpParams().set('idPost', idPost.toString()) } : {};
    return this.httpClient.post('url-delete',options);
}

public deletePost(idPost: number): Observable<any> {
    const params = new HttpParams({fromString: 'idPost=' + idPost.toString()});
    return this.httpClient.post('url-delete',params);
}
```

Comment: In chrome dev tools do you see the param being sent out via the actual request?

Comment: yes, in request payload the idpost appears

Comment: I noticed that your path is /delete, but your post url is /url-delete. Is it possible that is the issue or is that just a placeholder?

Comment: I just put url-delete to not put the whole url

Comment: 2nd paramater in `post` is the body. are you sure you want to send the paramters in the body?

Comment: Try adding details about what back end frameworks you might be using and adding the appropriate tags, That'll probably fast track you into getting this question in front of the right audience. If your request looks correct, then the issue is with how the back end is expecting your request to look. From the angular side, it appears you are doing everything by books, especially if the request goes out correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd Paramter in `post` is the body and the options should be a json like:

```
const options = { params: new HttpParams().set('name', 'xxx') }
```

Now invoke it like this:

```
public deletePost(idPost: number): Observable<any> {
    const options = {params: new HttpParams({fromString: 'idPost=' + idPost.toString()})};
    return this.httpClient.post('url-delete',{}, options); // empty body
}
```